# Await overriding previous variable in asynchronous method, multiple await

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Print(BasicSurveyReportViewModel paramModel)
{

    ActionResult OverallSummary =
        await basicSurveyReportController.OverallSummary(paramModel);
    ActionResult CompanyInfo =
        await basicSurveyReportController.CompanyInfo(paramModel);
    ViewBag.OverallSummary = OverallSummary;
    ViewBag.CompanyInfo = CompanyInfo;
    return View();
}
```

In this code, first `OverallSummary` variable is set successfully.

But when running at the `CompanyInfo` line's method, it puts the variable into both `CompanyInfo` and `OverallSummary`.

How do I can get the results into separate variables?

Comment: Your question is lacking in clarity. Are you saying that `ViewBag.OverallSummary` and `ViewBag.CompanyInfo` both point to the same object at the end of the method?

Comment: Top of two ActionResult variables overriding latest await result. also it will affecting `ViewBag.OverallSummary` and `ViewBag.CompanyInfo`.

Comment: That's not a sentence.

Comment: You need to clairfy when you say:  **But when running at the `CompanyInfo` line's method.**

Do you mean this line: `ActionResult CompanyInfo =
        await basicSurveyReportController.CompanyInfo(paramModel);`

Or this line: `ViewBag.CompanyInfo = CompanyInfo;`

I'm assuming the former, but not sure due to your variable naming

Comment: Also, if it is the first reference of `CompanyInfo`, then we're going to need to see code for the methods: `basicSurveyReportController.OverallSummary(paramModel);` and `basicSurveyReportController.CompanyInfo(paramModel);`

Comment: this line: ``ActionResult CompanyInfo = await basicSurveyReportController.CompanyInfo(paramModel);``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call asynchronous child actions, which are not supported in ASP.NET 4.x. I suspect that the ASP.NET controller is just accessing the *current* request when you return `View(blah)` or whatever from your child actions.

The only way to correctly do this (in the current version of ASP.NET) is to write helper methods that do the actual work and return your own types (not `ActionResult`):

```
OverallSummary GetOverallSummaryAsync(BasicSurveyReportViewModel model);
CompanyInfo GetCompanyInfoAsync(BasicSurveyReportViewModel model);

public async Task<ActionResult> Print(BasicSurveyReportViewModel paramModel)
{
  OverallSummary overallSummary =
    await GetOverallSummaryAsync(paramModel);
  CompanyInfo companyInfo =
    await GetCompanyInfoAsync(paramModel);
  ViewBag.OverallSummary = overallSummary;
  ViewBag.CompanyInfo = companyInfo;
  return View();
}
```

Then your other controller actions can convert to use those methods as well, like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OverallSummary(BasicSurveyReportViewModel paramModel)
{
  return View(await GetOverallSummaryAsync(paramModel));
}
```